# problem with emulator failing to start correctly

Tags: android, emulation

Since last week when I run a project it starts the emulator but sooner I got this message and I have to close and restart again otherwise it refuse to install the apk. Does someone know some reasons and what I have to do beside destroy and rebuild the Avd cause it doesn't make any change. Thank you. Here's the console lines

```
[2011-07-30 19:39:24 - NewStavanger] ------------------------------
[2011-07-30 19:39:24 - NewStavanger] Android Launch!
[2011-07-30 19:39:24 - NewStavanger] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-30 19:39:24 - NewStavanger] Performing com.wocmultimedia.NewStavanger.Main activity launch
[2011-07-30 19:39:24 - NewStavanger] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'avdGooglemarket'
[2011-07-30 19:39:24 - NewStavanger] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'avdGooglemarket'
[2011-07-30 19:39:31 - NewStavanger] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-07-30 19:39:31 - NewStavanger] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-07-30 19:40:46 - NewStavanger] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.wocmultimedia.NewStavanger.Main activity launch'!
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times wiping the user data off the emulator will fix those types of problems, I've had emulators get pretty buggy sometimes, especially if you constantly open and reclose them.  Reinstalling the emulator would likely fix the issue. If its setup is fairly simple, that should only take a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this site:

http://phonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-emulator-5554-disconnected.html

Comment: I will try it. Should this wipe user data erase all previous apps installed by me?

Comment: I tried and it hanged but maybe something is wrong in the 2.2 google api cause this problem is only with that platform. I have created another emulator 2.1 for other app and it never gave problem. I tried to recreate a new AVD but after 3 times it starts again with the problem. The work around I found is to make a first attempt then close the emulator when appear the home page and rerun the app then it will work till the end flowless.